# On element click Trigger event fire twice for input checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery

when i click on the div element should trigger click on checkbox only once but for some reason i get event fired twice , i saw other topics with similar problem but noone helped me

```js
$('div').click(function(e) {
  $('input').trigger('click');

  check();
});

function check() {
  if ($('input').is(':checked')) {
    console.log('input cheked')
  } else {
    console.log('unchecked')
  }
}
```

```css
.test {
  height: 150px;
  width: 150px;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="test">
  <input type="checkbox" name="">
</div>
```

Comment: The checkbox is inside the DIV, and the event bubbles out.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue is because the click occurs on the `div`, which triggers a `click` on the child checkbox which in turn propagates up the DOM and runs the click handler on the `div` again.

If you are trying to create a bigger hit-area for the checkbox, just use a `label` element instead. Then you get this behaviour for free without needing any JS.

If you want to know the state of a checkbox when it's changed, hook a `change` event handler to it. Try this:

```js
$(':checkbox').on('change', function() {
  if (this.checked) {
    console.log('input checked')
  } else {
    console.log('unchecked')
  }
});
```

```css
.test {
  height: 150px;
  width: 150px;
  background: red;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label class="test">
  <input type="checkbox" name="">
</label>
```

Comment: that is what im looking for , thanks . I dont understand only why if i wrap it in a div and label is different effect

Comment: It's because label elements have this behaviour by default. It's their main purpose. Div elements are just to compartmentalise blocks of HTML

Answer (score 0):

That is because, when you are trigerring click on the input the event is being **bubbles** to all its parents. To stop that use `e.stopPropagation` on the click event handler of input.

```
$('input').click(function(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
});
```

Read more about bubbling and capturing [here](https://javascript.info/bubbling-and-capturing).

Check the working code below:

```js
$('div').click(function(e) {
  $('input').trigger('click');
  check();
});

$('input').click(function(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
});


function check() {
  if ($('input').is(':checked')) {
    console.log('input cheked')
  } else {
    console.log('unchecked')
  }
}
```

```css
.test {
  height: 150px;
  width: 150px;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="test">
  <input type="checkbox" name="">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your checkbox is inside div and you are binding click evet to div and from that you are triggering checkbox click event which again triggers click of div. That's why it's triggering 2 times.

You can directly go for checkbox change event:

```js
$(':checkbox').on('change', function() {
  if (this.checked) {
    console.log('input checked')
  } else {
    console.log('unchecked')
  }
});
```

```css
.test{
  height: 150px;
  width: 150px;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="test">
 <input type="checkbox" name="">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

JQuery uses event bubbling when setting up events. This means that when you click the input the event is fired once for the input and then it 'bubbles' up the DOM tree to the parent DIV. This then notices the click event on the DIV and fires again. Therefore the event fires twice, once for the input and again for the DIV.

To stop this you will need to use the 'capture' technique instead of event bubbling. This would mean that you would use `addEventListener` and pass in the option as the third argument as true.

See here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener

Also see here to understand bubbling vs capturing: https://javascript.info/bubbling-and-capturing